# Devolver el nombre de la medalla que gano

Tags: javascript, array, condiciones, console

ojalá me pudieran ayudar. No entiendo cuál es mi error en el siguiente ejercicio:

Escribí la función medallaSegunPuesto, pero usando como máximo un sólo **if** y haciendo uso de los **arrays** te pueden ser útiles acá .

Por las dudas te recordamos que la función tiene que devolver la medalla que le corresponde a los primeros puestos de una competencia, por ejemplo:

Primer puesto: le corresponde "Oro"
Segundo puesto: le corresponde "Plata"
Tercer puesto: le corresponde "Bronce"
Otros puestos: le corresponde "Seguí participando"

Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
function medallasSegunPuesto(a) {
  if (a > 3)
    return "Seguí participando";
  return ["Oro", "Plata", "Bronce"](a - 1);
}


console.log(medallasSegunPuesto(1));
console.log(medallasSegunPuesto(2));
console.log(medallasSegunPuesto(3));
console.log(medallasSegunPuesto(4));
```

Pero me marca error, no sé que esta mal en el código. O alguna otra forma de resolverlo utilizando un SOLO if y haciendo uso de los array.

Gracias

Comment: A un array se le accede con paréntesis **cuadrados**, no redondos. Es decir, tienes que hacer: `return ["Oro", "Plata", "Bronce"][a - 1]`. También por favor, siempre incluye los errores que encuentras en tu pregunta, esto ahorra mucho tiempo y da un mejor prospecto de la situación que enfrentas.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por contestar, ya lo cambie a corchetes pero igual sigue saliendo error :(

Comment: ¿Cuál error? Por favor, siempre comparte tus errores.

Comment: Es `medallaSegunPuesto ` no `medallasSegunPuesto `. Por esto siempre comparte tus errores, así es más sencillo ayudarte.

Comment: @FranAcuna Muchas gracias, exactamente ese era el error. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es que no puedes interpretar un array como función, eso mismo te dice el error, para referirte al índice, usa corchetes (`[]`)

```js
function medallasSegunPuesto(a) {
  if (a > 3)
    return "Seguí participando";
  return ["Oro", "Plata", "Bronce"][a - 1];
}


console.log(medallasSegunPuesto(1));
console.log(medallasSegunPuesto(2));
console.log(medallasSegunPuesto(3));
console.log(medallasSegunPuesto(4));
console.log(medallasSegunPuesto(5));
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por contestar, ya cambie los paréntesis por corchetes pero me sigue saliendo estos errores:                                                                                                                       La función medallaSegunPuesto tiene que estar declarada
La función medallaSegunPuesto debe recibir un parámetro
La función medallaSegunPuesto(1) debe retornar "Oro"
La función medallaSegunPuesto(2) debe retornar "Plata"
La función medallaSegunPuesto(3) debe retornar "Bronce"

Comment: @GuadalupeValenzuela Eso es exactamente lo que hace la función, si tienes `console.log` en alguna parte, quítalos

Comment: Muchas gracias, el error ya no sale :)